# converting gradient to linear-gradient syntax

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm trying to convert a CSS style from gradient linear-gradient, but am a little confused about the syntax:

```
background: gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#BF942F), to(#BF942F), color-stop(0.5, #F8F8DC));
```

I know I can obviously remove the 'linear' parameter but I'm a bit lost after that:

```
background: linear-gradient(left top, right top, from(#BF942F), to(#BF942F), color-stop(0.5, #F8F8DC));
```

Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `left top, right top` should map to a single direction parameter: `to right`. The `top` bit is insignificant since this is a horizontal linear gradient.
- The `from`, `to` and `color-stop` functional notations are not used; instead the color stops are specified in order. Based on what you have, it looks like it should be `#BF942F, #F8F8DC, #BF942F`. Since each color stop is equidistant (0%, 50%, 100%) there is no need to specify the precise location of each one.

Hence:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #BF942F, #F8F8DC, #BF942F);
```

[Here's a comparison of the old and new syntaxes.](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/3jpsbsxo) Note that since the notation that you have is a WebKit invention, it *only* exists as `-webkit-gradient()` and thus can only be seen in a WebKit-based browser such as Safari or Chrome.